# Unity does not display properly

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

Ubuntu Unity on the Ubuntu netbook edition installs without a problem but when I log in though, where the panels are, there is just blank area with a shadow effect style thing on it. I can open apps but the Window buttons and the global menu are not visable.

Does this mean that I cannot use Unity. I'm running it through Wubi on a Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop.

My total ammount of graphics memory is 831MB
My dedicated memory is 128MB.

The odd thing is is that Windows Aero displays without a problem so why is there a problem with Unity

Hope this helps

Ben

Comment: What is your model of graphics card? You can find out by running:

> sudo lshw -C display

ATI cards are known to have problems with Unity.

Comment: This is offtopic for this site and should be reported as a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I think this is already reported as https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/593380

Comment: I can see nothing in the faq saying bugs are off topic, as per the closed comment this absolutely has to do with Ubuntu and developers for Ubuntu. This is a valid question the correct answer is: "This is a known problem (link to bug report) Plus (possible workaround)

Comment: I have same problem, Dell Latitude D531

Comment: *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
       resources: irq:19 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fea00000-feafffff

Comment: Have the same issues with a Dell D531 Latitude:

# sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
       resources: irq:19 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fea00000-feafffff

Any

Comment: I have the same problem on my Inspiron 1501 2GB RAM after a clean install. I have no problem using the Desktop Edition with Compiz enabled.

~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS482 [Radeon Xpress 200M]
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=66 mingnt=8
       resources: irq:17 memory:c

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. Please report it the developers by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `ubuntu-bug unity` and following the instructions. You might want to link to this question in your bug report to give the developers more information.